# Navigating to Different activities in Android

Tags: android, list, navigation

I have an Android app whose MainActivity contains a list of Chapters/Units let's say. 
Now when you click on it, each Unit has "N" number of topics as another list. 
When you open any one of them it has the topic explained, and at the bottom there are two "Next" and "Previous" buttons that takes you the next or previous TOPIC respectively. 
What happens is 
1. I open Unit I, then open Topic 1 and continue till I'm at Topic 8 by pressing "Next" button each time. 
2. Now when I press the Back/Up Navigation button I'm being taken to the previous Topic (Topic 7), which I don't want because I'll have to back 8 times to get back to the TOPIC LIST.

What I want is to be taken back to the TOPIC LIST directly instead of going back to previous activity. 
How do I achieve it?

Comment: write a logic for that..

Comment: Try explaining a question like this in a diagram.It will be much easier for readers.

Comment: I don't have that privilege yet.. @Hardeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The very simple solution to your issue is - 

on Previous and next click add finish();

something like this - 

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.previous:
                goToPreviousTopic();
                finish();
                break;

             case R.id.next:
                goToNextTopic();
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
```

So in background your main activity will be present and in activity stack there will be only one activity after the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thincking about 2 solutions abbout your your problem (but only if your topics are extends to activity):

First, you can override the onBackPressed method from Activity

`@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
 // Go to TOPICLIST
 }`

Second, you change the history of activities to disable the way to back on it.

`<activity  android:name=".activity.topic.subTopic"
            android:noHistory="true"></activity>`

Comment: What about when I have to come back to another Unit. Overriding onBackPressed causes trouble.